# Access denied for user 'DrChitraDhawle'@'ip-10-181-125-22.ec2.internal' (using password: YES)")

Tags: python, mysql, django, deployment, pythonanywhere

I am deploying my django website with MySQL database in python anywhere and its link is - http://drchitradhawle.pythonanywhere.com/ but on running the command

> python manage.py migrate

I am getting the following error on my bash-

django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'DrChitraDhawle'@'ip-10-181-125-22.ec2.internal' (using password: YES)")

> settings.py file is-

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'django _db',
    'USER': 'DrChitraDhawle',
    'PASSWORD': 'r.....6',
    'HOST': 'mysql.server',
    'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Database setting in python-anywhere is-

[image]

> **Note**:- I have just created the database name from Database tab, but not
>   created the actual database anywhere ie. i have not created any table
>   as i dont know where to create.

Comment: You need to provide access rights to the DB user for the django DB. I don't know how to do that on pythonanywhere. Use some other sql client and try to access the DB. This does not seem django related issue.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the database is wrong. The names are listed in the screenshot you provided. I'm guessing the one you want is `DrChitraDhawle$django_db`

Comment: Hey @Glenn thanks for your answer. But i tried changing the database name as DrChitraDhawle$django_db but it still giving the same error.

Comment: Did you reload your web app?

Comment: Yes i have reloaded it you can check it in link - http://drchitradhawle.pythonanywhere.com/

Comment: Are you using the right password? The password for MySQL is different to the password you use to log in to PythonAnywhere. There's a place to set it at the bottom of the databases page.

Comment: yes i have a different password for database which i set on Database tab of pythonanywhere which is different from login password.

Comment: let me tell u , I have just created the database name from Database tab, but not created the actual database anywhere ie. i have not created any table as i dont know where to create.

Comment: On running the command python manage.py syncdb , I am getting the same error

Comment: @RahulSatal, how did you do it?

Comment: @OfekGila in my situation I didn't created the database as my website do not require any database. But later I came to know that even I don't need any database in my website but still I have to create the database for Django. As django itself require some of the tables to work. So I just created database and my problem is solved. Hope this helps you.